# Spring Security configuration with role-based access returns a 403 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing a small application with Spring Security configuration and JWT token-based authorization and encountered a problem - when using hasRole() or hasPermission() methods to differentiate access to requests, even if the authorized user has the roles that meet the restrictions, the request still returns a 403 code.

**Implementing of UserDetails and UserDetailsService**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

  private final User user;

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return user.getRoles();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return user.getUsername();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return user.getIsEnable();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return user.getIsEnable();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return user.getIsEnable();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return user.getIsEnable();
  }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String exceptionMsg = String.format("User with username '%s' not found", username);
    return new UserDetailsImpl(userRepository.findUserByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(exceptionMsg)));
  }
}
```

**User entity and Roles**

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "username"})
public class User {
  @Transient
  private final String MAIL_REGEX =
          "^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be empty")
  @NotNull(message = "Username cannot be empty")
  @Size(min = 1, max = 90)
  private String username;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be empty")
  @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be empty")
  @Size(min = 8, max = 100)
  private String password;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  @Email(message = "Invalid email address", regexp = MAIL_REGEX)
  @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be empty")
  private String email;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
  private Set<Role> roles = Set.of(Role.USER, Role.ADMIN, Role.SUPER_ADMIN);

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Boolean isEnable = true;
}
```

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  USER, ADMIN, SUPER_ADMIN;

  @Override
  public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
  }
}
```

**Security configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
  RSAPublicKey publicKey;

  @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
  RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

  @Bean
  PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/hello").hasAuthority("USER");
    http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    http.sessionManagement(session ->
            session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS));
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler());

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(publicKey).build();
  }

  @Bean
  JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).build();
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
  }
}
```

If I try to query the /hello path, it returns a forbidden error, despite the fact that the authorized user has all the possible roles. Can you tell me what could be the problem? A long time ago I did everything exactly as it is now and everything worked without errors.

Tried to add ROLE_ prefix, make roles without enum class with clear string format, applied both hasRole() and hasAuthority() methods

Comment: and you have enabled debug logging and looked in the logs that tell you exactly why you are getting a 403?

Comment: HttpSecurity calls to configure the http instance are usually chained, by calling  the method always on the original object you take the risk to loose the previous configuration setup, if any of the configuration method returns a new object...